# How to get element by its partial class name CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am creating few css buttons and would like to style them as short as possible so I started 
like this

```
[class*='mybuttons-button']{
    margin-top:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:6px 12px;
    color:#fff;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

which will affect all elements that contain class `my-button`

now I want to get deep in to it and do this

```
[class*='-large']{
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size:120%;
    line-height: 1.33;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -khtml-border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
}
[class*='mybuttons-button-color']{
    background:blue;
}
```

but since the class  `-large` might come up in some 3rd party CSS added by user I would like to be more specific and say something like this instead

```
[class*='mybuttons-button-*ANYTHING*-large']
```

so that I dont have to do this

```
mybuttons-button-color-large
mybuttons-button-red-large
mybuttons-button-green-large
mybuttons-button-color-medium
mybuttons-button-red-medium
mybuttons-button-green-medium
```

Does anyone know a way to do this? Is it possible at all, to nail the middle word instead contains only?

I know I can space the class names etc , but would love to give this a try since, to me, this**

```
<span class="mybuttons-button-color-large"></span>
```

looks cleaner than this:

```
<span class="mybuttons-button color large"></span>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selector

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not possible and is really unnecessary given the other form you have shown. It may look less clean to you but it *definitely* doesn't to me

Comment: Like said just wanted to give it a try it would be nice to know if it is possible at all. But I have not seen anything similar either.

Comment: I've tried to combine begin and end attribute selector. http://jsfiddle.net/zYLYG/9/ i don't know if is what you need

Comment: Generally, performing partial matches on class names is problematic, precisely due to the nature of class names being potentially numerous, and the fact that they are whitespace-separated. If this were the only class name then you could use attribute selectors as mentioned, but since 3rd-party code could add other classes to the same elements, that just complicates matters.

Comment: @KevinBoucher, it's actually https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors now.

Comment: @keypaul This is what I was looking for and it works great for me! But as BoltClock points out, you have to be careful with 3rd-party code.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In the same way you can do this `.class.class2.class3 { /*styles*/ }` to target only things that have all 3 classes, you can can combine attribute selectors to do the same:

```
[class*="mybuttons-button"][class*="-large"] { /*styles*/ }
```

Granted it won't work in a case like this:

```
<span class="my-buttons-button-color-small something-else-large"></span>
```

since it contains both `mybuttons-button` and `-large`.

If you didn't think that would happen or be an issue you should be fine.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3wEJe/

Definitely wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: These are called attribute selectors.

Comment: Why do you have to use the asterisk symbol (*) after class? I guess this is CSS3.

Answer (score -3):

If you separate your class names, then you can use CSS selectors to only grab an element with two classes, instead of relying on wild cards, as so:

```
<span class="mybuttons-button color large"></span>

.mybuttons-button.large {
    font-size: 120%
}
```

Remember that ".class1.class2" is different than ".class1 .class2" (with the space): the first looks for an element with BOTH classes; the second looks for descendants of class1 that are class2.

Comment: Well sorry if I misunderstand the end goal. If you want keep your classes together with dashes, this could work: [class*="my-button"][class*="large"] to target only classes with large in the name that also have my-button